# virtual joystick driver (VJoyD) and Direct Input

Tags: c++, device, drivers, wdk

I have couple of questions:

1. What is exactly VJoyD used for? Based on my reading win WDK (Windows Driver Kit) it provides joystick services in Windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542258(v=vs.85).aspx). If that is the case, can I use it to send commands from my hardware to Vjoyd so my hardware can look like a joystick?
2. Direct Input is used mostly to read input devices but I want to do the opposite, I would like to write data to direct input so that it becomes availabe in video games, ie. have custom hardware translate information to Direct Input so it is like a joystick.
   There's in WDK (dinputd.h), is that what you would use? Any examples would be much helpful, even if it is one-liner to sent input axis value to DInput.

Btw, I am aware of PPJoy but not going to use it because this is for commercial use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own questions for the benefit of others:

1.A: VJoyD used by old version of OS to handle joystick input, dead by now.

2.A: In the past, you there were some alternatives but now replaced by HID class.

Comment: +1 On both your question and answer just for following up and providing the results of your inquiry to everyone else.